# Can fictional abilities of a character be protected by copyright?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Some examples of abilities from games:

- In Dota 2, the hero Queen of Pain has a ability/skill called *Scream of Pain*. It is essentially a kind of "magical" scream that damages nearby enemies.
- In the Warcraft universe the so called "night elves" have an ability called *shadowmeld* that makes them invisible, leaving only the shadows.

Are abilities like these protected by copyright? Also, there are any court cases regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your example powers are tropes and their basis in public domain

The Queen of Pain's scream is modeled after the Banshee, which had a scream that would kill... and there are LOTS of variants of Banshee. In fact, ["Our Banshees Are Louder"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurBansheesAreLouder) is a trope.

Hiding in a shadow or walking through it is for example a typical feature of Ninja stories since the Edo Period, and a common Trope as ["Shadow walker"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShadowWalker). That makes those two powers older than

### You can not have a copyright on concepts, facts, or ideas.

Facts are not copyrightable, which was decided LONG ago over *Feist v Rural.* Neither can you copyright concepts or ideas. You won't get a claim on the concept of a damaging scream or turning into shadow. See also [Copyright.gov](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html) (emphasis mine):

> How do I protect my idea?
>
> Copyright does not protect ideas, concepts, systems, or methods of doing something.  You may **express** your ideas in writing or drawings and claim copyright in your description, but be aware that **copyright will not protect the idea itself as revealed in your written or artistic work.**

Comment: Good catch with the Banshee comparison.

Comment: @ohwilleke You also can't copyright a fact of nature, for example, Dave Matthews has this ability.